# Xcode - Using SMS text in APP

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sms

my scenario: 
I have a device which can send an SMS by error with the error code.
This device have an own sim card. Now I would like the error code which come with sms to my iPhone automatically in my app to analyze. 
My thought :
The app starts and look into my "sms folder" if there are messages from "special numbers with an error code" and copy the last one into my app
My solution now is to copy the sms and paste it in a text box which I convert into my app...

I hope my english is not so bad.

Best regards 
John

Comment: Did you jailbreak your phone? This isn't possible without jailbreaking, because a third party app doesn't have access to the SMS transcripts. At least not with iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not working without Jailbreak.